# Why is $\mathfrak{sl}(n)$ the algebra of traceless matrices?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I'm studying Lie algebras as purely algebraic objects, without much of a background in the differential geometry surrounding Lie groups.

The definition of  $\mathfrak{sl}(n)$  has been given to me as the algebra of traceless $n\times n$ matrices with multiplication $$[A,B]=AB - BA$$
With my limited knowledge of differential geometry, I roughly understand that $\mathfrak{sl}(n)$ is defined as the tangent space of the Lie group $SL(n)$ at the identity, but I don't see how this leads to the definition of $\mathfrak{sl}(n)$ as the traceless $n\times n $ matrices.

I was hoping that someone would be able to roughly explain (or point me in the direction of a not-too-differential-geometry-technical article):

> 1) What is the reason $\mathfrak{sl}(n)$ is taken to be the algebra of **traceless** $n \times n$ matrices?
>
> 2) What is the connection between $\mathfrak{sl}(n)$  and $SL(n)$?
>
> 3) What is the motivation for this definition?

Comment: You exponentiate elements of $sl(n)$ to get elements in $SL(n)$. There is a nice relationship between traces and determinants which supplies the proof that $sl(n) $ is the set of traceless matrices. This definition is an equivalent form of the usual definition of the Lie algebra given a Lie group, which becomes apparent after you trudge through the hint I gave.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a Lie group $G$, there is an exponential  map $\operatorname{exp}:g\to G$ (where $g$ is the corresponding Lie algebra) such that $\operatorname{exp}\{tA\}$ is just the one-parameter subgroup of $G$ with tangent vector $A$ at $e$. For matrix groups, this is just the usual matrix exponential $e^{At}$. Now note that $\operatorname{det}e^A=e^{\operatorname{tr}A}$.

Comment: Is there an easy way to see why $\det e^A = e^{\operatorname{tr}A}$ holds?

Comment: Yes. First prove it for a diagonal matrix (for intuition), then for a Jordan form matrix, then for any matrix (use the Taylor expansion of the exponent function).

Comment: @LinAlgMan Alternatively: $\frac{d}{dt}e^{At}=Ae^{At}$. Hence $\frac{d}{dt}\operatorname{det}(e^{At})=\operatorname{tr}A\operatorname{det}(e^{At})$ by Liouville's theorem.

Answer (score 11):

There is a purely geometrical explanation. First, let $n=2$, and consider $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$.

Let $X : [0,1) \to \mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ be a smooth path, with $X(0) =E$, where $E$ is the identity.

$$X(t) = \left[\begin{array}{cc} a(t) & b(t) \\ c(t) & d(t) \end{array}\right]$$
where $\det[X(t)] = (ad-bc)(t) = 1$ for all $t$. The derivative $X'(t)$, as $t$ tends to zero, gives a tangent vector to $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ at $E$. We have
$$X'(t) = \left[\begin{array}{cc} a'(t) & b'(t) \\ c'(t) & d'(t) \end{array}\right]$$

Since $ad-bc \equiv 1$ we can differentiate to give
$$a'd+ad'-b'c-bc'\equiv 0$$
Since $X(0)=E$ we know that $a(0)=1$, $b(0)=0$, $c(0)=0$ and $d(0)=1$. Hence:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
a'd+ad'-b'c-bc' &\equiv& 0 \\ \\
a'(0)\,d(0)+a(0)\,d'(0)-b'(0)\,c(0)-b(0)\,c'(0) &=& 0 \\ \\
a'(0)+d'(0) &=& 0
\end{eqnarray*}$$
This tells us that $X'(0)$ must be a traceless matrix.

**General Dimension**

[Jacobi's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula) tells us that

$$\det(X)' = \mathrm{tr}\! \left[ \mathrm{adj}(X)X' \right] $$

Since $\det(X) \equiv 1$ we have $\det(X)'\equiv 0$. When $t=0$, $X=E$ and so $\mathrm{adj}(X) = E$. Hence 
$$\mathrm{tr}\!\left[X'(0)\right]=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Fix $A\in \mathfrak{sl}(n)$. Then, $\exp(tA)=e^{tA}\in SL(n,\mathbb{R})$. Thus, $\det(e^{tA})=1$ for every $t\in\mathbb{R}$. Also, let $J$ be the Jordan Canonical Form of $A$, with $A=PJP^{-1}$. This way,differentiating both sides:
    $$0=\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\det(e^{tA})=\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\det(Pe^{tJ}P^{-1})=\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\det(e^{tJ})=(I).$$
Note that $Spec(tJ)=Spec(tA)$ and that $Spec(e^{tA})=e^{tSpec(A)}$. Moreover, the determinant of a triangular matrix is the product of its diagonal entries, which in the case of the Jordan Form they are exactly the matrix' eigenvalues. Thus,
$$\det(e^{tJ})=\prod_{\lambda\in\operatorname{Spec(A)}}e^{tA}.$$
This way,
    $$(I)=\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\prod_{\lambda\in\operatorname{Spec(A)}}e^{tA}=\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}e^{\sum_{\lambda\in Spec(A)}t\lambda}=\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}e^{t\cdot tr(A)}=tr(A).$$

Therefore $\mathfrak{sl}(n)\subset\{A\in\mathfrak{gl}(n):tr(A)=0\}$. Note that, a trace is a rank 1 linear function, both these spaces are $n^2-1$ dimensional. Thus, they coincide.