# Lie algebra of $\mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{C})$ using method of differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am asking a new question because people did not understand what  I meant and closed the other question.
I know that the lie algebra of $\mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{C})$ are traceless matrix and I can proof it. What I am interested is proof it using the methods of differential geometry.

Let $\gamma(t)$  be a curve on a manifold $M$ and $f$ a real function. We define the vector $V$ as the operator
$V\cdot f=\frac{d}{dt}f(\gamma )$

Now let $U$ be the set
$$
U:=\left\{\left(\begin{array}{ll}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{array}\right) \in \mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{C}) \mid a \neq 0\right\}
$$
and define the map
$$
\begin{array}{l}
x: \quad U \rightarrow x(U) \subseteq \mathbb{C}^{*} \times \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C} \\
\left(\begin{array}{ll}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{array}\right) \mapsto(a, b, c)
\end{array}
$$

Te Lie algebra $\mathcal{L}(G),$ of a Lie group is defined by
$$
\mathcal{L}(G):=\left\{X \in \Gamma(T G) \mid \forall g, h \in G:\left(\ell_{g}\right)_{*}\left(\left.X\right|_{h}\right)=X_{g h}\right\}
$$
which can be  proved to be isomorphic to the Lie algebra $T_{e} G$ with Lie bracket
$$
[A, B]_{T_{e} G}:=j^{-1}\left([j(A), j(B)]_{\mathcal{L}(G)}\right)
$$
induced by the Lie bracket on $\mathcal{L}(G)$ via the isomorphism $j$
$$
\left.j(A)\right|_{g}:=\left(\ell_{g}\right)_{*}(A)
$$
Any $A \in T_{\left(\begin{array}{ll}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right)} \mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{C})$ can be written as
$$
A=\alpha\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{1}}\right)_{\left(\begin{array}{ll}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)}+\beta\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{2}}\right)_{\left(\begin{array}{ll}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)}+\gamma\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{3}}\right)_{\left(\begin{array}{ll}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)},
$$
then we can show that $$j\left(\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{1}}\right)_{\left(\begin{array}{l}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)}\right)=x^{1} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{1}}-x^{2} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{2}}+x^{3} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{3}}$$
$$j\left(\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{2}}\right)_{\left(\begin{array}{l}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)}\right)=x^{1} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{2}}$$

$$j\left(\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{3}}\right)_{\left(\begin{array}{l}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)}\right)=x^{2} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{1}}+\frac{1+x^2x^3}{x^1}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{3}}$$
and so
$$
 j(A)=(\alpha x^1+\gamma x^2)\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{1}}\right)+(-\alpha x^2+\beta x^1)\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{2}}\right)+\left(\alpha x^3+\gamma\frac{1+x^2x^3}{x^1} \right) \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{3}}\right) \tag 1
$$
On the other hand we can show that by other method  that the lie algebra of $\mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{C})$ consist of traceless matrices.

My question is how can we identify $(1)$ with a traceless matrix?

Comment: Don't the answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/870833/why-is-mathfraksln-the-algebra-of-traceless-matrices) use methods of differential geometry?

Comment: @ Dietrich Burde They are defining a vector as derivative of a curve on a manifold. In differential geometry vector are operator. See my definition

Comment: Well, the definitions are equivalent. When it comes to dealing with matrix groups one typically uses the curves definition of tangent vectors.

Comment: @ Alekos Robotis So if they are equivalent then we should be able too proof that $(1)$ is a traceless matrix. That is what i  want too proof

Comment: @amiltonmoreira Differentiating the coordinate chart map $x$ defines a local diffeomorphism $T_I x : T_1 SL \to T_1(\Bbb C^* \times \Bbb C \times \Bbb C) \cong T_I \Bbb C^3$. Now, we can recover the coordinate representation of the tangent vector corresponding to $j(A)$ by evaluating at $x(I) = (1, 0, 0)$, giving $j(A)_{(1, 0, 0)} = \alpha \partial_1 + \beta \partial_2 + \gamma \partial 3$. By construction the corresponding matrix is $(T_I x)^{-1} j(A)_{(1, 0, 0)} \in T_1 SL(2, \Bbb C)$, and using your explicit formula for $T_1 x$ you can show that matrix is tracefree.

Comment: Could you give me an answer showing that it is trace free?

Comment: It seems that since you asked that question you've done so yourself. Notice that the map $\rho$ in your answer is the same as the map $(T_I x)^{-1}$ in my previous comment.

Comment: The easiest way, I think, is to observe that along the level set $\det A = 1$ in the space $\mathrm{gl}(2,\mathbb{C})$ of all square matrices, the determinant function has maximal rank. Therefore, the level set is a smooth submanifold of $\mathrm{gl}(2,\mathbb{C})$, and its tangent space at $I$ is the kernel of $d(\det A)$ at $I$. This is easily seen to be the set of traceless matrices.

Answer (score 2):

The proof is still really the same as the standard one. But here it is using the definition of a tangent vector as a derivation.
$\newcommand{\SL}{\mathrm{SL}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\gl}{\mathrm{gl}}
\renewcommand{\sl}{\mathrm{sl}}$

Let $\sl(2,\C)$ denote the space of trace-free $2$-by-$2$ complex matrices. Consider the smooth map (which really consists of 4 separate scalar functions):
\begin{align*}
  f: \SL(2,\C) &\rightarrow \gl(2,\C)\\
  A &\mapsto \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
Given any tangent vector $V \in T_I\SL(2,\C)$, there exists a curve $\gamma(t)$ such that $\gamma(0) = I$ and $\gamma'(0) = V$. Then
\begin{align*}
  Vf(I) &= \left.\frac{d}{dt}f(\gamma(t))\right|_{t=0}\\
        &= \begin{bmatrix} a'(0) & b'(0) \\ c'(0) & d'(0) \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
Differentiating $\det \gamma(t) = ac-bd = 1$ with respect to $t$ at $t = 0$, we get
$$
a'(0) + d'(0) = 0.
$$
This defines a linear map $T_I\SL(2,\C) \rightarrow \sl(2,\C)$.

Conversely, given any $A' \in \sl(2,\C)$, let $\gamma(t) = (I + tA')/(\det (I+tA'))$. Let $V = \gamma'(0)$. Then, a straightforward calculation shows that
\begin{align*}
  Vf(I) &= \left.\frac{d}{dt}f(\gamma(t))\right|_{t=0}\\
        &= A'.
\end{align*}
This shows that linear map is surjective.

Answer (score 0):

From the formula above we can prove that

$$\left[\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{1}}\right)_{\left(\begin{array}{ll}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)} ,\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{2}}\right)_{\left(\begin{array}{ll}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)} \right]=2\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{2}}\right)_{\left(\begin{array}{ll}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)}$$
$$\left[\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{1}}\right)_{\left(\begin{array}{ll}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)} ,\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{3}}\right)_{\left(\begin{array}{ll}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)} \right]=-2\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{3}}\right)_{\left(\begin{array}{ll}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)}$$

$$\left[\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{2}}\right)_{\left(\begin{array}{ll}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)} ,\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{3}}\right)_{\left(\begin{array}{ll}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)} \right]=\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{1}}\right)_{\left(\begin{array}{ll}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)}$$

Now we define the linear map $$\rho \left(\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{1}}\right)_{\left(\begin{array}{ll}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)}\right)={\left(\begin{array}{ll}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1
\end{array}\right)}=X_1$$
$$\rho \left(\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{2}}\right)_{\left(\begin{array}{ll}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)}\right)={\left(\begin{array}{ll}
 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right)}=X_2$$
$$\rho \left(\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{3}}\right)_{\left(\begin{array}{ll}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)}\right)={\left(\begin{array}{ll}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right)}=X_3$$

Now $\left[X_1,X_2 \right]=2X_2 \quad$,$\left[X_1,X_3 \right]=-2X_3\quad$,$\left[X_2,X_3 \right]=X_1\quad$
Since $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{1}}\right)_{\left(\begin{array}{ll}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)} \quad$,$\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{2}}\right)_{\left(\begin{array}{ll}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)}$ and $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{3}}\right)_{\left(\begin{array}{ll}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)}$ are basis of this lie algebra  $\rho$ is a representation of the lie algebra of $\mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{C})$.

So traceless matrix are representation of the lie algebra of $\mathrm{SL}(2, \mathbb{C})$